# Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInitd00bfc7ec47fbf7b35605d09893589e5' not found. How to debug this error?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Please help me to come out from this error. It is generated by the following snippet:

```
?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInitd00bfc7ec47fbf7b35605d09893589e5::getLoader()
```

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Is it possible that some part of your `vendor` folder had been erased? Just try to run `composer install`, all the vendor folder should be "reinstalled" and new autoload classes should be generated.

Comment: @honzalilak but already it contains code part, how should we recover only missed files.

Comment: @Ram I am not sure whether it is possible to recover only missed files. When debugging weird things with missing files/classes with composer, I sometimes erase the whole vendor folder and run `composer install` which downloads all dependencies. I am not sure whether composer has a mechanism to identify only missing files.